# Is column span is possible to be float in html?

Tags: html

I have one coloumn in table which should be the 2.5 in width of the row above it and is it posssible that once i give that much extract of width than the first coloumn of above row should not be affected?

Comment: The 2.5 *what*?  You mean, 2.5x (like, if the previous row was 100, this one would be 250)?  No, this is not possible just with HTML - you'd need JavaScript to do it.  Furthermore, this would have very shaky browser support, since most browsers will expect all columns to have the same width across all rows.  You'd need to use divs or something instead of a table.

Answer (score 0):

No that type of control is not possible with colspan. Have you thought about using `div` instead of a table?

Comment: As you asked so nicely, look at this: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di